# Facebook Graphi API user Request returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have two Facebook applications (websites) using the OAuth login from Facebook functionality.  One works, the other gives me a 400 error when I request the user data.  The request looks like this:

[https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,username,locale,location&access_token=[token](https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,username,locale,location&access_token=%5btoken) returned by earlier calls]

Both websites use the exact same code (but get their app IDs and app secret from a db call).  The token request and token check are returning OK, it's when I go ahead and ask for the user data, then I get an error.

Ideas?
TIA,
Owen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has to be with the access token. Try debugging the access token to confirm.

Comment: The debug_token function returns OK.

Comment: [https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)
Is this what you tried?

Comment: Yes.  It returns the name of the app, the name of the user, and other info about the token.  No errors here...

Comment: Does it include all the permissions required by you app?

Comment: Also check to see if the request url is in the proper format after you  create it. If you are concatenating your access token to obtain the request url, compare it with a sample request url to ensure it is the proper format.

Comment: Hmmm. I used the GraphAPI explorer and for the site that is not working, it is telling me that username has been deprecated (error 12). Not sure why the first site is still working with username in the list of fields... ?  If I take out "username", then the 2nd site works!